What are the scss variables for modifying a Vuetify 3 v-text-field outline?
I have several v-text-field in a form. I want to modify the color of the outline that has been added through Vuetify's variant="outline" prop. I am trying to add the relevant scss variables in my main.scss file like so:


@use 'vuetify/settings' with (

  $input-outline-color: #E9DEFC,

  $input-outline-active-color: #CFBCFF,

  $input-outline-inactive-color: #E7DFF6

);



@use 'vuetify' as *;

@use 'vuetify/styles';

I have looked in Vuetify's API documentation for v-text-field, field and input. I cannot find the appropriate variable names, however. I expect to be able to add the relevant variable names to my main.scss file and modify the default colors for the outline in its native, active and passive states.

are you talking about vuetify2 or vuetify3?

My apologies. I'm talking about Vuetify 3.

I have edited the question clarifying it's a Vuetify 3 issue.

Haven't found any predefined scss variable either...
Adding a custom class .custom-outline on the v-text-field, and apply CSS below should work:
<v-text-field
    ...
    outlined
    class="custom-outline"
  ></v-text-field>

Styles:
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.custom-outline :deep(.v-field__outline__start) {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.custom-outline :deep(.v-field__outline__end) {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.custom-outline :deep(.v-field__outline__notch) {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>


Thank you for your answer. However, the v-text-field is applying the outline by way of variant="outlined". I tried your solution. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I think it might have something to do with the variant prop.

@Chris I just tried with it, it seems you are correct, the latest class name should be like yours. BTW, since ::v-deep has been deprecated, I have update the answer to use :deep(selector) instead.

sure, glad to help!

I discovered the solution. For the outlined variant of Vuetify 3 v-text-field, there are three elements deep within the v-text-field that need to be targeted. Those three elements have these three classes respectively:
.v-field__outline__start
.v-field__outline__notch
.v-field__outline__end

Targeting these is a bit tricky. We need to employ Vuetify's::deep selector like so:
.custom-outline ::v-deep .v-field__outline__start {
  border-color: red !important;
}
.custom-outline ::v-deep .v-field__outline__end {
  border-color: red !important;
}
.custom-outline ::v-deep .v-field__outline__notch {
  color: red !important;
}

